# What is wrong with my code? My program will not compile

Tags: c++

Ok, so my assignment is to build on an existing code from the book. I have to add the 3rd box and then calculate the total for all 3 boxes. Here is what I've written so far, but it will not compile. Please help me find the problem. Thanks.

The program I'm using is MS Visual C++ and the complile error I get is

> error C2447: '{' : missing function header (old-style formal list?)

referring to the { after my int Total_Volume line

```
// Structures_and_classes.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
class CBox // Class definition at global scope
{
public:
 double m_Length; // Length of a box in inches
 double m_Width; // Width of a box in inches
 double m_Height; // Height of a box in inches
};
int main();
int Total_Volume;
{
CBox box1;
CBox box2;
CBox box3;
 double boxVolume = 0.0;             // Stores the volume of a box
  box1.m_Height = 18.0;            // Define the values
  box1.m_Length = 78.0;             // of the members of
  box1.m_Width = 24.0;              // the object box1
  box2.m_Height = box1.m_Height - 10;         // Define box2     Box 2 H = 8
  box2.m_Length = box1.m_Length/2.0;          // members in    Box 2 L = 39
  box2.m_Width = 0.25*box1.m_Length;           // terms of box1  Box 2 W = 6
  box3.m_Height = box1.m_Height + 2;         // Define box3     Box 3 H = 20
  box3.m_Length = box1.m_Length - 18;          //members in    Box 3 L = 50
  box3.m_Width = box1.m_Width + 1;           //terms of box1   Box 3 W = 25 

  // Box1
  boxVolume = box1.m_Height*box1.m_Length*box1.m_Width;cout << endl;
<< "Volume of box1 = " << boxVolume;
  cout << endl;
  // Box 2
  boxVolume = box2.m_Height*box2.m_Length*box2.m_Width;cout << endl;
<< "Volume of box2 = " << boxVolume;
  cout << endl;
  // Box 3
  boxVolume = box3.m_Height*box3.m_Length*box3.m_Width;cout << endl;
<< "Volume of box3 = " << boxVolume;
  cout << endl;

//Calculate Total Volume
  Total_Volume = (box1.m_Height*box1.m_Length*box1.m_Width)+
      (box2.m_Height*box2.m_Length*box2.m_Width)+
      (box3.m_Height*box3.m_Length*box3.m_Width);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: please format your code.

Answer (score 8):

Change:

```
int main();
int Total_Volume;
{
```

to:

```
int main()
{
    int Total_Volume;
```

That will fix your immediate problem, although I suspect you'll have a few more questions today :-)

The actual problem with your current code is that it defines a prototype for main, followed by a file-level variable, followed by a naked brace, which is why it's complaining about a missing function header.

You *may* also want to consider changing your `main` function to one of:

```
int main (int argc, char *argv[])
int main (void)
```

(probably the second in your case) as these are the two forms required to be supported by the ISO C standard. Implementations are free to accept others if they wish but I usually prefer my code to be as standard as possible. The reason I say *"may"* is because it's not necessarily required to get your code working, more of a style thing.

Comment: awesome! that helped and I was able to complete the rest on my own. thanks paxdiablo!

Comment: @Russton - I'd be nice and mark this as an accepted answer, then. It gives paxdiablo some rep, and shows the question has an answer available for people with similar queries.

Answer (score 3):

```
int main();
int Total_Volume;
{
```

should be

```
int main()
{
  int Total_Volume;
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you mixed up a couple lines:

```
int main();
int Total_Volume;
{
CBox box1;
CBox box2;
CBox box3;
```

looks like it should be:

```
int main() {
  int Total_Volume;
  CBox box1;
  CBox box2;
  CBox box3;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try moving

```
int Total_Volume;
```

after the {

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @bitmask: Please read my answer again. It provides an answer to the question. In fact, it contains the exact same advice as 4 other answers all submitted within a minute of each other.  Evidently, I didn't win the [FGIW](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9731/fastest-gun-in-the-west-problem), but it is not a critique or request for clarification.

Comment: Maybe I'm nitpicking but it suggests to try something instead of stating what is wrong. Besides that; Your answer is actually wrong, as moving the declaration after the `{` would leave the semicolon after `main()` which would still not compile. Granted, the answer time seems to be identical for all posts, but this answer just adds noise as it doesn't add details not also presented by the other -- more thorough -- answers (and you wouldn't loose rep, btw.).

Comment: @bitmask: The use of "Try" here is just idiomatic courtesy - politely hiding the illocutionary force, to make it sound like a helpful suggestion from an equal rather than a rebuke. The extra semicolon - a minor, but a fair point. The noise? meh.

Answer (score 0):

Goodness me. Please check the preview and at least make sure your question looks like prose plus some code. *Edit* okay, let's assume that was a glitch that's been sorted out. The rest of my answer still holds.

A little bit of digging suggests the first problem is that you don't have a properly defined main() function. This is the first thing one learns about C++ typically, so in the first instance get that right.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You probably intended to write:

```
int main()
{
     int TotalVolume;
```

You can't start a block where you did.
You have declared that there will be a function `main()`, and that there's a global variable TotalVolume, but the anonymous block following these is not allowed.